# The KnpSnappyBundle Is Not Working

Tags: symfony, pdf, permissions, pdf-generation

I am trying my best to understand why the KnpSnappyBundle does not work at all. Inside of Symfony2.

This is the error I keep getting time and time again:

```
 Warning: file_put_contents(/var/folders/l7/_w4sky2d457czb5v3d0133y40000gn/T/knp_snappy52eb2be7bf7915.98143786.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php line 330
```

This is line 330:

```
 file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

I have done everything to the "T" with exactly how it explains how to install it.

I have installed WKHTMLTOPDF using HomeBrew and it now resides in my /usr/local/bin directory.

My config.yml file looks like this:

```
 # Knp Snappy Configuration
 knp_snappy:
 pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "wkhtmltopdf"
    options:    []
```

My code looks like this:

```
 return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml("hello world"),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="'.$pdfTimeStamp.'.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

I can generate a pdf from command line when calling this code:

/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com/ /User/xxxxx/Desktop/thepdf.pdf

And yet I get this error everytime.

PLEEEEEASE HELP! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your shell user has write permissions for /var/folders/l7/_w4sky2d457czb5v3d0133y40000gn/T/.

Answer (score 0):

try to use these binary path /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf instead of using the wkhtmltopdf.